# Converting byteArray to image virtualy

Tags: java, html, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a function that returns the image as `byteArray` and the cause is that I don't want to save the image physically in the harddisk but I am creating it dynamically and reading it from memory as `byteArray`.
I have a zoomer demo where he is reading the image in like this :
 `<a href="path/to/largeImage"><img src="path/to/smallImage"/></a>` 
I used `<p:graphicImage />` instead of `<img src="path/to/smallImage"/>` and it worked but the `<a />` element is the problem which component can fit instead of `<a/>` or what is the solution with this `<a/>` element.

Comment: what about `<h:link>` or `<h:outputLink>` in jsf 2. It renders `<a/>` tag with get request.http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/

Comment: i tried them the '<h:link>' has outcome which is the name of page found in the directory or the outcome of a faces-config navigation case also the '<h:outputLink>' didn;t succeed since the return type is stremedContent or a byteArray which can't be value for an outputLink to render to an a with src as image